# Where to get the potentiometer that comes with Arduino kit

Tags: potentiometer

Does anyone know where I can get the potentiometer that comes with the Arduino kit? You can see them [here](http://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/Potentiometer.PDF).

[They are sold out on their website](https://store.arduino.cc/product/C000013).

Comment: There is a radio shack in your town. Kailus-Kona. You can pick up any pot you like there

Answer (score 2):

It's just any old trimmer pot. It's nothing special. Why do you feel you need that specific one? Any pot (of the right value) will do.  What value is it? (That datasheet is a generic one for all values).

Visit your favourite electronics retailer (IRL or on line) and pick a pot that is a suitable value and jiffles your tipples.

Comment: 10k. I just want these because I've used them and know they work for what I want. Try to find anything like these on Amazon. None of them have knobs.

Comment: Amazon is not an electronics retailer.  Any linear tracked 10K pot "will work" for you. Everything else is just looks.

Comment: Ok please find me a link to any site that sells trimmer pots with knobs.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=trimmer+pot+knob&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=trimmer+pot+knob&tbm=shop

Comment: Here's one, https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9288 but it's not a trimmer pot

Comment: That google search didn't help. I tried that.

Comment: Please, tell me *why* you feel you need a trim pot with a knob? Why not a trim pot without a knob, or a normal pot? What is so special about a trim pot with a knob?

Comment: Because it's perfect for a servo that only rotates 180 degrees. And I need the knob to turn it. lol

Comment: What on god's earth has the style of pot got to do with the fact that a servo rotates 180°?

Comment: I thought a trimmer pot turns only 180 degrees. The Arudino one I have does. I ordered some other ones and they spin in circles.

Comment: They spin in circles because you force them past the end of the track. Keep doing that and you will probably break them.  If you want to have a pot only work for 180° then program it to only work for 180° - don't rely on finding a very esoteric pot that can't be found. Settle for a cheap generic one and do the rest in software.

Comment: Software isn't going to stop the knob from spinning around. Like I said the Arduino ones found above do exactly what I need. They aren't like volume knobs, they rotate only a certain amount.

Comment: Normal pots only rotate a certain amount. Cheap trim pots can very easily be forced around too far, often without knowing it.  The actual sensitive area will only be somewhere between 180 and 270°.